# Как сделать удаление ManualResetEventSlim из ConcurentDictionary

Tags: c#

Как сделать грамотное удаление ManualResetEventSlim из ConcurentDictionary? Как гарантировать, что ManualResetEventSlim не кем не используется? Перед удалением мне нужно будет ещё вызвать Dispose

```
public class Worker
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ManualResetEventSlim> _etpIdToReadyEventSlim = new();
    private readonly DefaultRtsMarketWaiterSettings _settings = new();
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new();

    public Task WaitProcedureAsync(Procedure procedure,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim readyEventSlim;
        
        lock (_syncRoot)
        { 
            readyEventSlim = _etpIdToReadyEventSlim.GetOrAdd(procedure.EtpId, 
                (_) => new ManualResetEventSlim());
        }

        Task.Run(() => DoWaitAsync(procedure.EtpId, readyEventSlim, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

        readyEventSlim.Wait(cancellationToken);

        //Здесь следует сделать удаление

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task DoWaitAsync(string etpId,
        ManualResetEventSlim readyEventSlim,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        
        DateTime startsAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        try
        {
            while (DateTime.UtcNow - startsAtUtc < _settings.MaxWaitingTimeSpan)
            {
                try
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Id работы: {id}");

                    await Task.Delay(_settings.BetweenChecksDelay, cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            readyEventSlim.Set();
        }
    }
}


public class Procedure
{
    public string EtpId { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultRtsMarketWaiterSettings
{
    public TimeSpan MaxWaitingTimeSpan { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    public TimeSpan BetweenChecksDelay { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего просто не вызывать `Dispose` у `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Этот метод делает две вещи:

1. освобождает `WaitHandle` *если он был создан*;
2. запрещает дальнейшую работу с объектом.

Если вы замените все вызовы `readyEventSlim.Wait` на `readyEventSlim.WaitAsync` - `WaitHandle` никогда создан не будет, а значит и освобождать его будет необязательно.

---

Однако самое правильное решение тут - вовсе не использовать этот класс: для синхронизации вы можете использовать непосредственно объект Task.

Для начала, в текущем виде вы можете просто избавиться от ConcurrentDictionary и писать `return Task.Run(() => DoWaitAsync(...);`, поскольку ваш ManualResetEventSlim ничего не делает кроме создания паразитных связей.

Поэтому я предположу, что ваша задача - избежать запуска нескольких одновременных циклов. В таком случае можно воспользоваться подсчётом ссылок. Начнём со вспомогательного класса:

```cs
    private class Worker
    {
        public readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        public Task waitTask = null!;
        public int refCount;
    }

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Worker> workers = new();
```

Дальше всё просто, надо лишь аккуратно обработать все возможные случаи:

```cs
    public async Task WaitFor(string etpId, CancellationToken token)
    {
    again:
        var worker = workers.GetOrAdd(etpId, new Worker());

        Task waitTask;

        lock (worker)
        {
            if (worker.refCount < 0)
            {
                // Редкий случай, когда мы попали точно на момент остановки цикла.
                // Сейчас воркера уже нет в словаре, надо лишь попробовать ещё раз.
                goto again;
            }

            if (worker.refCount++ == 0)
            {
                // Это первое обращение к воркеру, запускаем цикл ожидания
                worker.waitTask = Task.Run(() => DoWaitAsync(etpId, worker, worker.cts.Token));
            }

            waitTask = worker.waitTask;
        }

        try
        {
            await waitTask.WaitAsync(token);
        }
        finally
        {
            lock(worker)
            {
                if (--worker.refCount == 0)
                {
                    // Это было последнее обращение к воркеру, останавливаем цикл ожидания и удаляем воркера из словаря
                    worker.refCount = -1;
                    worker.cts.Cancel();

                    workers.TryRemove(new(etpId, worker));

                    // прямо сейчас метод DoWaitAsync может ещё выполняться, но по завершению waitTask
                    // на воркера не останется никаких ссылок, самое время освободить ресурсы
                    worker.waitTask.ContinueWith(_ => worker.cts.Dispose(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но всё же как мне улучшить мой код, чтобы он корректно отрабатывал? Параллельно циклы могут работать

Comment: К тому же метод GetOrAdd не является атомарным

Comment: @dimka0074 он не является атомарным в том плане что может вызвать лямбду несколько раз. Но если побочных эффектов у неё нет - использовать его безопасно.

Comment: @dimka0074 если у вас параллельные циклы могут работать - выкидывайте словарь, события и всю чушь которую написали. Просто вызывайте ваш DoWaitAsync напрямую.

Comment: Параллельно циклы работать не могут всё же, я сейчас проверил этот кейс. Тогда с учётом этого как можно исправить мой код? Я не вижу у ManualResetEventSlim методы WaitAsync()